# Append the struct elemnts in a array

Tags: ios, swift, struct, codable

I have a struct and want to get the count of elements in it and append the values in a array, but unable to find a way to do this.

```
struct User_notification_preferences : Codable {
  let comments : Bool?
  let likes : Bool?
  let dislikes : Bool?
  let unfollow : Bool?
  let follow : Bool?
  let updates : Bool?
}
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case follow = "follow"
    case likes = "likes"
    case unfollow = "unfollow"
    case comments = "comments"
    case updates = "updates"
    case dislikes = "dislikes"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    follow = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .follow)
    unfollow = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .unfollow)
    likes = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .likes)
    dislike = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .dislikes)
    comments = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .comments)
    updates = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .updates)
```

}

I am using this to show and update the UISwitch values based on backend response. What would be the best way to do this? Below is the output after decoding the JSON response and I want the desired output as a array of dictionary [[String:Bool]].

[image]

Comment: What does the desired result look like?

Comment: I have edited my question for more details, thanks!

Comment: `switchStatus` is a dictionary and not an array. If a property `User_notification_preferences` is nil, should it be replaced by false in the values of `switchStatus`?

Comment: Want it have as a array of dictionaries, so I can use the dictionary key and values according to their index in tableview.

Comment: The way you wrote it in your question, it is a dictionary. You still haven't answered how you'd like to represent nil values in this dictionary?

Comment: I have the values in dictionary as you saw in above screenshot "notificationPrefrence", the problem is I want it to have these key:value as an array of dictionary and I am getting this response on Mirror children "<_RandomAccessCollectionBox<LazyMapCollection<DictionaryLiteral<String, Any>, (label: Optional<String>, value: Any)>>"

Comment: In your question *the desired output is* a dictionary. If you want an array of dictionaries, you should include that in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181671/discussion-between-bmacin-and-carpsen90).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mirror :

```
let pref = User_notification_preferences(comments: true, likes: false, dislikes: nil, unfollow: true, follow: nil, updates: false)

let prefMirror = Mirror(reflecting: pref)

var switchStatus: [String:Bool] = [String:Bool]()

prefMirror.children.forEach { child in
    guard let label = child.label else {
        fatalError("Couldn't get the label")
    }
    switchStatus[label] = child.value as? Bool ?? false
}

print(switchStatus) //["follow": false, "updates": false, "unfollow": true, "dislikes": false, "likes": false, "comments": true]
```

This will work even if you modify the properties of `User_notification_preferences`.

Or, you could use a naïve function like this:

```
struct User_notification_preferences : Codable {
    //...
    func dictionaryRepresentation() -> [String:Bool] {
        return ["comments": comments ?? false,
                "likes": likes ?? false,
                "dislikes": dislikes ?? false,
                "unfollow": likes ?? false,
                "follow": likes ?? false,
                "updates": likes ?? false
        ]
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
print(pref.dictionaryRepresentation()) //["follow": false, "updates": false, "comments": true, "likes": false, "dislikes": false, "unfollow": false]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get encode it in key value pair then get whatever you want:

```
let userNotiPre  = User_notification_preferences()
let jsonDatas = try JSONEncoder().encode(userNotiPre)

if let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonDatas, options: []) as? [String: Hashable]{
   //Get all values from dict and then you can also get count of that array 
   let array = dict.values
   array.count
}
```